# How to extract Column names and its values from the Database table, which are concatenated

Tags: sql, db2

Separate the column values which are concatenated in a Database Table (column_name1, values1, columnname2, values2, ....), parsing the string.

I have a table, e.g "tab1" and has a column name " rule_sql".

"rule_sql" column has the following values -

```
COUNTRY_CODE IN ('766') COMPANY_CODE IN ('03') COLLECTION_UNIT_CODE IN ('000099')   
COUNTRY_CODE IN ('624') COMPANY_CODE IN ('02') COLLECTION_UNIT_CODE IN ('BE0001','000COM','000INT','00FSCY')
```

Column even have values like -

```
COLLECTION_UNIT_CODE IN ('006800','000205','999999','110009','007279') COUNTRY_CODE IN ('869') COMPANY_CODE IN ('01')
```

Columns names to be extracted/parsed are not in one order.

Expected result is -

```
COUNTRY_CODE || COMPANY_CODE || COLLECTION_UNTI_CODE

766           || 03          || 000099
624           || 02          || BE0001,000COM, 000INT, 00FSCY
869           || 01          || 006800,000205,999999,110009,007279
```

Comment: Please add what you have already tried to archive your goal. Have you tried regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regex_replace()`:

```
select 
    regexp_replace(rule_sql, '^.*COUNTRY_CODE IN \(([^)]+)\).*$', '\1') country_code,
    regexp_replace(rule_sql, '^.*COMPANY_CODE IN \(([^)]+)\).*$', '\1') company_code,
    regexp_replace(rule_sql, '^.*COLLECTION_UNIT_CODE IN \(([^)]+)\).*$', '\1') collection_unit_code
from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bba66ef2eeda66cc31d431b2ea1ef8ba)**:

```
with mytable as (
    select 'COUNTRY_CODE IN (''766'') COMPANY_CODE IN (''03'') COLLECTION_UNIT_CODE IN (''000099'')' rule_sql from dual
    union all select 'COUNTRY_CODE IN (''624'') COMPANY_CODE IN (''02'') COLLECTION_UNIT_CODE IN (''BE0001'',''000COM'',''000INT'',''00FSCY'')' from dual
)
select 
    regexp_replace(rule_sql, '^.*COUNTRY_CODE IN \(([^)]+)\).*$', '\1') country_code,
    regexp_replace(rule_sql, '^.*COMPANY_CODE IN \(([^)]+)\).*$', '\1') company_code,
    regexp_replace(rule_sql, '^.*COLLECTION_UNIT_CODE IN \(([^)]+)\).*$', '\1') collection_unit_code
from mytable
```

```
COUNTRY_CODE | COMPANY_CODE | COLLECTION_UNIT_CODE               
:----------- | :----------- | :----------------------------------
'766'        | '03'         | '000099'                           
'624'        | '02'         | 'BE0001','000COM','000INT','00FSCY'
```

---

Note: to remove the remaining quotes, then you wrap the results with `replace()`:

```
select 
    replace(regexp_replace(rule_sql, '^.*COUNTRY_CODE IN \(([^)]+)\).*$', '\1'), '''', '') country_code,
    replace(regexp_replace(rule_sql, '^.*COMPANY_CODE IN \(([^)]+)\).*$', '\1'), '''', '') company_code,
    replace(regexp_replace(rule_sql, '^.*COLLECTION_UNIT_CODE IN \(([^)]+)\).*$', '\1'), '''', '') collection_unit_code
from mytable
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=90452d7e3a348393ca3e50039c93dc8f)**:

```
COUNTRY_CODE | COMPANY_CODE | COLLECTION_UNIT_CODE       
:----------- | :----------- | :--------------------------
766          | 03           | 000099                     
624          | 02           | BE0001,000COM,000INT,00FSCY
```